# ¿Cómo añadir una variable a un data.frame que codifique otra variable del mismo data.frame?

Tags: r, bucle-for

Tengo que añadir una variable con un bucle en un data.frame y no lo consigo.

Tengo este data.frame

```
ingresos<-c(5,10,20,50,100,500,1000,2000)
gastos<-c(10,20,40,50,50,100,500,2000)
saldo<-c(-5,-10,-20,0,50,400,500,0)
datos<-data.frame(ingresos,gastos,saldo)
```

Tengo que añadir una nueva variable al data frame llamada Cod_Saldo que codifique la variable Saldo de la siguiente manera (Usando un bucle que recorra el contenido del data frame).
▪ 1 si tiene saldo negativo
▪ 2 si saldo positivo
▪ 3 si saldo cero

Lo he intentado así:

```
datos$Cod_Saldo<-datos$saldo+0
for(i in datos$Cod_Saldo){
  if(i==0) {datos$Cod_Saldo<-3} 
  if(i<1) {datos$Cod_Saldo<-1} 
  if(i>1) {datos$Cod_Saldo<-2}
}
```

pero me da error

¿Alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que tienes una confusión en como se trabaja en R, cuando haces esto:

```
if(i==0) {datos$Cod_Saldo<-3}
```

Imagino que estás suponiendo que se actualiza `Cod_Saldo` de la fila correspondiente a  la iteración, pero no es así, esta sentencia actualiza todos los valores de `Cod_Saldo` en el `data.frame`. Además tienes un problema de lógica, las condiciones se superponen al ser independientes: `if(i==0)` y `if(i<1)`

Para hacer lo que buscas debes modificar algo el código:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(datos)) {
  
  if (datos$Cod_Saldo[i] == 0) {
    datos$Cod_Saldo[i] <- 3 
  } else if (datos$Cod_Saldo[i]  < 1) {
    datos$Cod_Saldo[i] <- 1
  } else if (datos$Cod_Saldo[i]  > 1) {
    datos$Cod_Saldo[i] <-2
  }
  
}
```

Estamos iterando por el índice de fila para poder modificar directamente el valor en cada fila y hemos anidado las condiciones para que no se "pisen".

Ahora bien, en R el enfoque iterativo en la mayoría de los casos no tiene ningún sentido, por que existen las funciones "vectoriales" como el `ifelse()`, que permite anidar condiciones. Esto hace lo mismo de una forma más compacta y legible:

```
datos$Cod_Saldo <- ifelse(datos$saldo == 0, 3, 
                          ifelse(datos$saldo > 0, 2, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

usando `tidyverse` puedes hacer un `mutate` con un `case_when` para definir las condiciones

```
datos <- datos %>% 
  mutate(Cod_Saldo = case_when(saldo < 0 ~ 1,
                               saldo > 0 ~ 2,
                               saldo == 0 ~ 3))
```